# Are UUID4s distributed evenly across the md5 address space?

Tags: md5, distribution, uuid, sharding

(I will preface this question by saying I think there is virtually no way that UUID4 would be *designed* not to be uniformly distributed, but I lack the math skills and crypto knowledge to prove it.)

In streaming a bunch of data to kinesis, we are experiencing a problem where one shard, shard #4, is very hot and the other seven shards are underloaded. Kinesis distributes data across its shards by a [partition key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html#partition-key), which is a unicode string that it converts to an md5 hash.

Shards are sequential by default, so if you have one shard it will have all partition keys from 0 - 2^128 in it. We have eight shards, so the buckets are bounded at increments of 2^125. The end of each shard range is, in hex,

```
0x20000000000000000000000000000000
0x40000000000000000000000000000000
0x60000000000000000000000000000000
0x80000000000000000000000000000000
0xa0000000000000000000000000000000
0xc0000000000000000000000000000000
0xe0000000000000000000000000000000
0x100000000000000000000000000000000
```

We partition based on a UUID 4. We had assumed that that would be evenly distributed across the above address space, but with this "hot shard" problem I'm starting to wonder. UUID4s are 2^128 bits, but [they reserve six bits for deterministic information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#section-4.4), leaving 2^122 values that can be random. It's those six bits that give me pause.

Trivially, if I take the six most significant bits away, my largest possible value is 2^122, which will certainly fall in the first or second bucket, all the time. But back in reality those six digits aren't the most significant of the UUID4 space, so what effect do they have on the distribution? If I use a UUID4 for a sharding key, will my data be evenly distributed across the shards?